# placing a loader next to a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

im trying to add a loader next to a button, I'm using bootstrap spinner

this is my code :

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <div class="fiboForm">
            <h1>Fibonacci Calculator</h1>
            <label for="number">The Fibonacci Of</label>
            <input class="userInput" type="number" id="number" name="amount" min="0" max="50">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="isBtn">Is</button>
            <span id="result">
                <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-danger" role="status"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried display:flex on the form tag, also tried to add class and add margins didn't work.

This is the best result I manage to get:

[image: this is the best result I manage to get]

Comment: Here's your HTML without any additional CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/q0xu62tg/

Comment: Here's a proper bootstrap form: https://jsfiddle.net/hneL523u/

Comment: helped me a lot, thanks!